Capitalization of SURNAMES
When I started using the complimentary Legacy software (v10) today, I came across the comment by Geoff Rasmussen that the convention of putting a surname in all caps is a thing of the past. I am wondering if that is true, and if I should join Geoff in converting all the upper case surnames to lower case (ie, JASZEWSKI to Jaszewski).

Logically, the question to ask is why capitalise in the first place. I suspect that the answer is that it made names stand out on a piece of (mostly) handwritten paper. Today the highlighting function should be done by the clarity of the user interface in question. On that basis, there is no need to manually capitalise surnames.
Certainly, FamilySearch advise that the surnames should now be written in normal case - not that everyone follows such advice. My response to continuing to capitalise is firstly that there's no need - user interfaces are designed to be legible and there is no inherent meaning in such capitalisation. Worse, a view is growing that capitalising is "shouting" so that's another reason not to do it.

It also removes information about capitalisation within the surname (e.g. Lejeune vs LeJeune).

Thank you for your answer!

The convention of "all caps = shouting" in online communication is at least as old as online communication, but the idea already existed a century earlier (see this History Stack Exchange question: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41249/when-did-people-decide-that-all-caps-means-the-writer-is-shouting.) The old genealogical convention uses a somewhat broader concept, of majuscule = emphasis; I can't offhand find a history of that idea, but it doubtless developed shortly after the Carolingian innovation of mixing miniscule and majuscule.

I am impressed at your ability to invoke the Carolingians! Not the usual sort of reference!

Capitalization of surnames in family trees used to be done to make it easier to find the surnames in books or on charts or reports and to distinguish the surname from the person's given names.
For example, the book "Finding Your Roots - The Official Handbook for Heritage Hunters" by Jeane Eddy Westin, copyright 1977, states:

Record each person's full name, capitalizing the entire surname. For
example, BARNES, John Joseph.

Back then, genealogical reports were printed or typed. But with the advent of computerization, it has been realized that doing this loses information about the spelling of the surname. e.g. from the capitalized surname "DELUCA", it would not be known whether the correct spelling is Deluca, DeLuca or deLuca.
Some genealogy programs today have the ability to capitalize surnames in your reports for you if you find that preferable. But if you enter your names all capitalized, few programs are able to de-capitalize and the best those can do is to assume the first letter is capitalized which would then incorrectly display names like deLuca. So it is best for you to enter your surnames correctly, and leave the display to the program.
Tamura Jones goes one step further to say that the ability of some programs to capitalize surnames is a major misfeature. See his article from 2011: Five Freaky Features Your Genealogy Software should not have.
My personal preference is to enter surnames into my program with the correct capitalization, and then display the surname in a bold font to make it more visible, e.g. Barnes, John Joseph.  It would be nice if more programs had this option.
